# clone a git repository using git init, fetch, and checkout

Tags: c++, libgit2

**Introduction**

I'm doing experimentations using the popular `libgit2` written in C.
I'm trying to do a `clone` but using an un-common way. In order, the git commands:

1. `git init`
2. `git remote add origin https://repository.git`
3. `git fetch origin`
4. `git checkout master`

By using `git bash` and the following commands, I can get an existing repository with all its history.

**Question**

Now, let's see my current C++ implementation. The following code is trying to copy the behaviour of the previous written git commands.

```
#define url         "https://repository.git"
#define path        "./"
#define user        "user"
#define pass        "pass"

/** credential callback **/
int credentials(git_cred **cred, const char *, const char *, unsigned int, void *) {
    return git_cred_userpass_plaintext_new(cred, user, pass);
}

class Git {
public:
    Git() {
        git_libgit2_init();
    }

    ~Git() {
        git_repository_free(repository);
        git_libgit2_shutdown();
    }

    void update() {
        init();
        fetch();
        checkout();
    }

private:
    void init() {
        assertSuccess(git_repository_init(&repository, path, GIT_CVAR_FALSE));

        git_remote *remote = nullptr;
        git_remote_callbacks options = GIT_REMOTE_CALLBACKS_INIT;

        assertSuccess(git_remote_create(&remote, repository, "origin", url));

        options.credentials = credentials;
        git_remote_connect(remote, GIT_DIRECTION_FETCH, &options, nullptr, nullptr);
    }

    void fetch() {
        git_remote* remote = nullptr;
        assertSuccess(git_remote_lookup(&remote, repository, "origin"));

        git_fetch_options options = GIT_FETCH_OPTIONS_INIT;
        options.callbacks.credentials = credentials;
        assertSuccess(git_remote_fetch(remote, nullptr, &options, nullptr));
    }

    void checkout() {
        git_checkout_options options = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT;
        options.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_FORCE;

        assertSuccess(git_checkout_head(repository, &options));

        assertSuccess(git_checkout_index(repository, nullptr, &options));

        assertSuccess(git_repository_set_head(repository, "refs/heads/master"));
        git_object *treeish = nullptr;
        assertSuccess(git_revparse_single(&treeish, repository, "master"));
        assertSuccess(git_checkout_tree(repository, treeish, &options));
    }

    void assertSuccess(int error) {
        if (!error) return;

        const git_error *e = giterr_last();
        std::cout << "code: " << e->klass << " error: " << e->message << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

private:
    git_repository *repository = nullptr;
};

int main() {
    Git git;
    git.update();
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, this does not work. Running this program (calling `Git().update()`), I'm getting the following error during the checkout step:

```
code: 4 error: reference 'refs/heads/master' not found
```

The git repository has been created and I can see the remote origin that has been set successfully though `git bash`. I can do a manual `git checkout master` from `git bash` so I guess my current implementation of `checkout` is a failure.

Could someone highlight me about this error? I couldn't find enough resources nor support on all found example on internet.

**EDIT**
Since testing my code might help, let me give my `CMakeLists.txt` for compile `libgit2`. (source code https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(test)

include_directories(libgit/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${LIBSSH2_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_subdirectory(libgit)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

add_executable(test src/Git.h)
target_link_libraries(test git2)
```

Comment: Can you talk a little bit about why `git clone` doesn't work for you?

Comment: I need to setup a git repository in a folder that is not empty

Comment: so basically impossible with git clone

Comment: That makes sense, but you might be able to get it working by moving the files elsewhere and then back in. If your FS has cheap renames, it might be easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The missing link is that, since you're building a repository from scratch, your repository is still unborn (ie, its `HEAD` points to a non-existent `refs/heads/master` ref). On top of that, `checkout`'s only concern in libgit2-land is about bringing out files from the ODB, it doesn't write or update references.

Hence, you are missing the step where `git checkout` uses (in all likelihood) `git update-ref` to make `master` point to `origin/master`'s OID, and you can do that via [git_reference_create and friends](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/reference/git_reference_create).

Something like the following (brain-compiled):

```c
static int setup_tracking_branch(char *branch_name, git_reference *upstream)
{
    git_reference *tracking;
    git_oid up_oid = git_reference_target_peel(upstream);
    char *ui_name;

#if 0
    /* should be constructed from `upstream`. IIRC there are some
     * git_reference accessors that can help
     * (eg. `refs/remotes/origin/heads/master` is `origin/master`).
     */
#else
    ui_name = "origin/master";
#endif

    if (git_reference_create_matching(&tracking,
                                      git_reference_owner(upstream),
                                      branch_name, up_oid, 0, NULL, "branch: created from %s", ui_name) < 0 ||
        git_branch_set_upstream(tracking, git_reference_name(upstream)) < 0) {
        printf("failed to create remote-tracking branch\n");
        return -1;
    }

cleanup:
    git_reference_free(tracking);

    return 0;
}
```

This takes the name you want the new branch to be (`-b`), and the remote branch to track (`-t`), though it is clearly not a complete reimplementation, or even correct, so YMMV.

Comment: could you provide a complete example please?